# ios UICollectionView remove header programmatically

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I want have a control of the header of a UICollectionView as I need to remove and add it based on user-generated events.

What I have tried so far:

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout referenceSizeForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{

    if(toRemoveHeader){

        return CGSizeZero;

    }else{

        return CGSizeMake(320, 45);

    }
}
```

And then call `[self.collectionView reloadData]` whenever the user-event is generated. I would prefer to make this without reloading the data. Any ideas?

Comment: Hi! How you has solved this? =D

Comment: I dont think i solved it...

Answer (score 5):

If you are using Swift you can do it this way in your `UICollectionViewController` subclass:

```
var hideHeader: Bool = true //or false to not hide the header

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {
    if hideHeader {
        return CGSizeZero //supplementary view will not be displayed if height/width are 0
    } else {
        return CGSizeMake(30,80) //size of your UICollectionReusableView
    }
}
```

Comment: or if you want to get the existing size of the header view as specified in the storyboard, replace the CGSizeMake(30,80) line with this: `let headerView = self.view.subviews[0].subviews[0] as! UICollectionReusableView
        let existingSize = headerView.frame.size
        return existingSize`

Answer (score 2):

Your implementation is fully functional, the problem might be that you don't assign the object implementing that function to the `delegate` property of your `collectionView`.

The function `collectionView:layout:referenceSizeForHeaderInSection:` is implemented by a class confirming to the `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` protocol, and the `collectionView` expects its `delegate` to implement this method, and **not** its `dataSource`.

In one of my implementations I show a `footer` only if there are no cells in that `section`, and as long as the `delegate` property is set correctly it works perfectly.

```
#pragma mark - UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout

- (CGSize) collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
                   layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout
referenceSizeForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSUInteger count = [self collectionView: collectionView
                     numberOfItemsInSection: section];
    CGFloat footerHeight = (count == 0) ? 60.f : 0.f;
    CGFloat footerWidth = collectionView.frame.size.width;
    return CGSizeMake(footerWidth, footerHeight);
}
```